# Failed to pull tasks from management center while running java project with Hazelcast Mancente Configuration

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am trying to run hazelcast-man center with following configuration

```
   Config config = new Config();
    config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
 config.getManagementCenterConfig()
      .setUrl("http://localhost:8080/mancenter/");
    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

then console output is 
:-

> `Jun 03, 2018 12:25:07 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node WARNING:
>   [192.168.43.9]:5705 [dev] [3.8.1] Config seed port is 5701 and cluster
>   size is 1. Some of the ports seem occupied! Jun 03, 2018 12:25:07 PM
>   com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService INFO:
>   [192.168.43.9]:5705 [dev] [3.8.1] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast
>   Management Center on address:  http://localhost:8080/mancenter/ Jun
>   03, 2018 12:25:07 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService INFO:
>   [192.168.43.9]:5705 [dev] [3.8.1] [192.168.43.9]:5705 is STARTED Jun
>   03, 2018 12:25:08 PM
>   com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager INFO:
>   [192.168.43.9]:5705 [dev] [3.8.1] Initializing cluster partition table
>   arrangement... Jun 03, 2018 12:25:08 PM
>   com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService INFO:
>   [192.168.43.9]:5705 [dev] [3.8.1] Failed to pull tasks from management
>   center Jun 03, 2018 12:25:08 PM
>   com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService WARNING:
>   [192.168.43.9]:5705 [dev] [3.8.1] Failed to send response,
>   responseCode:404 url:http://localhost:8080/mancenter/collector.do

`

Comment: Can you please check if your Management Center deployed at "http://localhost:8080/mancenter/"? It looks like Hazelcast cluster cannot  find Management Center at the configured address.

Comment: I deployed man-center war in tomcat webapps. it is getting extracted and there is no error log of tomcat server but  
 "localhost:8080/mancenter/" is giving 404.

Comment: if I remove war from tomcat and i start hazelcast from terminal using this command  java -jar /path/to/war 8080 mancenter    , then it says address already in use

Comment: Can you try to clear port 8080 and try again with `java -jar ...` command? Or you can try a different port altogether

Comment: What is the import associated with the Config class?  Can't seem to find reference to this in documentation(?).   Can this configuration somehow be integrated/combined with JCache's  MutableConfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the Hazelcast Management Center WAR file directly

`java -jar hazelcast-mancenter-[version].war`

then an embedded Jetty is used and the URL is

- `http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter/` in newer versions (3.10+)
- `http://localhost:8080/mancenter/` in older versions (3.9 and older)

If you deploy the WAR file into a application server or a servlet container of your choice, then

- either use the default path - usually just copy the WAR name without suffix into URL (E.g. if you have `hazelcast-mancenter-3.10.1.war`, then the URL will be `http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter-3.10.1/`)
- or use your server native way to change the context path.

#### Tomcat

When you are deploying into Tomcat container, you can change the context path by editing `[TOMCAT_INSTALLATION]/conf/server.xml` file.
For instance if you want to deploy `hazelcast-mancenter-3.10.1.war` under `/hazelcast-mancenter/` path, then

- copy the WAR into `[TOMCAT_INSTALLATION]/webapps/` directory
- add a new `<context/>` element under the `<host/>` element in `server.xml`:

```
<Server ...>
  <!-- ... -->
  <Service ...>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Engine ...>
      <!-- ... -->
      <Host ...>
        <!-- ... -->
        <Context docBase="hazelcast-mancenter-3.10.1.war" path="/hazelcast-mancenter"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the problem is that you are running both the your hazelcast-mancenter and your project in same ports i.e 8080. I would recommend you to change the port in tomcat configuration.